# Nav bar doesn't expand and contract when screen size in changed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get my nav bar to collapse and expand as I change screen size. The code I have doesn't seem to work and I really can't see the problem.

I want the nav bar to collapse into a menu icon when the screen gets to roughly the screen size of a tablet. At the moment the nav links simply move in an unintentional way when the screen size is changed.

Please see code below:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;    
}

body {   
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

nav {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', Sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    width: auto;
 }

.navbar { 
 margin: 0; 
 padding-top: 1.5em; 
    padding-bottom: 1.5em; 
    padding-left: 6em;
    padding-right: 5.06em;

 background-color: #000; 
 } 


.navbar-brand {
 color: #fff; 
 background-color: #000; 
    font-size: 22px;
    display: inline; 
}

.navbar ul li {  
 display: inline; 
 } 
 

.navbar ul li a { 
 color: #fff; 
 background-color: #000; 
    font-size: 18px;
 } 

.nav-link {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">

    <link href="graphic-design.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
      
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-feJI7QwhOS+hwpX2zkaeJQjeiwlhOP+SdQDqhgvvo1DsjtiSQByFdThsxO669S2D" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
      
  </head>

 <body>   
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="logo"><img src="9haus-logo-white.png" alt="9haus logo" width="63px" height="19px"></a>   
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="graphic-design.html">Graphic design</a>
  <div class="navs">
    <ul class="navbar-brand">
      <li class="active"><a class="nav-link" href="graphic-design.html">Work</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="graphic-studio.html">Studio</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a></li>
    </ul> 
    </div>  
</div>      
</nav>     
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you tried the official bootstrap navbar ? the one that have the class navbar-collapse ? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar

Comment: Your code doesn't include bootstrap.css

Comment: @ZimSystem what do I need to do?

Comment: Start with Bootstrap basics, [read the docs](https://getbootstrap.com), use the [starter template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template), and use the [navbar shown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#supported-content) in the docs. You don't need all that extra CSS! Here's you navbar with a little effort applied from the docs: https://www.codeply.com/go/LF9Xk4F5BG

Comment: Alright I'll go back. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your Bootstrap 4 navbar isn't working as expected is simply because you aren't using the navbar components properly.

Here's a working version of the Bootstrap 4 navbar. You can see that with all components in place (and positioned properly) it does indeed work as expected (and does not require any unnecessary css hacks or JS hacks):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="graphic-design.html">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/60" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        Graphic design
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Work <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Studio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

It is also recommended that you avoid using custom css hacks when using Bootstrap 4 because custom css hacks tend to require more css hacks to fix the problems caused by the original css hacks. And in your particular case, most of your custom css is unnecessary because Bootstrap 4 provides native classes to do things like padding, margins etc.

Here's a reference link to Bootstrap 4 spacing utilities:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Note that the spacing classes (like most Bootstrap classes) are actually responsive. So, you can adjust the spacing for every single breakpoint as needed.

Comment: Hi. And uptick for answering the question

Comment: Solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I deleted my answer. @Chidz